# Where can I find the duration of a bus trip on Gran Canaria?

Tags: buses, canary-islands, gran-canaria

On 21 December, I will travel by bus from Aeropuerto Gran Canaria via Las Palmas de Gran Canaria to Agaete/Puerto de Las Nieves. I found [timetables for buses on Gran Canaria](http://www.globalsu.net/es/lineas.php) and I found out I need to take line 60 from the airport to Las Palmas and then line 103 from Las Palmas to Agaete. However, I can't find anywhere how long the bus ride takes. Since I'm going to take a ferry, it is important to know the arrival time at the bus stop closest to the ferry terminal at Agaete.

Where can I find more precise timetables for buses on Gran Canaria? Google Transit doesn't know. Is there any other search engine I may use to find arrival times, or, equivalently, the duration of the bus ride?

Comment: Can't find any offical information. Onlu rumours and links to the globalsu.net.

Answer (score 3):

One option appears to be a [shuttle](http://www.tourshuttle.com/EN/SPAIN/transfer_Gran-Canaria-Airport_Agaete.html), if you would consider that.

It  runs from the airport to Agaete, and appears to take 1 hour and 20 minutes.

At the very least, that should help give you an idea of the time it takes.

Comment: Hmm, that shuttle looks considerably more expensive than an ordinary local taxi would be, unless Gran Canaria taxis are much more expensive than taxis in the Alicante area on the Iberian peninsula.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use google maps it gives you more or less the time you will need to go by bus to Agaete, this is the cheapest option you have. I live in Gran Canaria and that works, you will need more or less 2 hours by bus[image]

If you will take ferry there is fred olsen free bus from Las Palmas, parque santa catalina to Agaete Harbour